# How to refresh activity when I click on new button

Tags: android

When I click on the new game button it doesn't refresh my game it still in the old one anyone can help me how to solve it. Here my code

**Menu Game Class**

```
public class MenuScreen extends ListActivity {
public static final String NEW_GAME = "new_game";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final String[] ACTIVITY_CHOICES = new String[] {
            getString(R.string.menu_new_game),
            getString(R.string.menu_prefs)
        };
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_screen);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ACTIVITY_CHOICES));
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
            switch(arg2) {
            case 0:
                startGame();
                break;
            case 1:
                startPrefs();
                break;
            default: break;
            }

        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
}

private void startGame() {
    Intent launchGame = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    launchGame.putExtra("SENDER", "MenuScreen");
    startActivity(launchGame);
}

private void startPrefs() {
    Intent launchPrefs = new Intent(this, Setting.class);
    startActivity(launchPrefs);
}}
```

**Play Game Class**

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String COME_FROM = "come_from";
    private int[] id_mc = new int[16];
    private Integer[][] img_mc = new Integer[16][2];
    private Button[] myMcs = new Button[16];
    private int mc_counter = 0;
    private int firstid = 0;
    private int secondid = 0;
    private Boolean mc_isfirst = false;
    private int correctcounter = 0;
    private TextView tFeedback;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Boolean b_snd_inc, b_snd_cor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        initGame();
    }
    private void initGame() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("memoryPrefs", 0);
        b_snd_cor =settings.getBoolean("play_sound_when_correct", true);
        b_snd_inc =settings.getBoolean("play_sound_when_incorrect", true);      
        mc_counter = 0;
        firstid = 0;
        secondid = 0;
        mc_isfirst = false;
        correctcounter = 0; 
        tFeedback = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mc_feedback);
        // setup button listeners
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game_menu);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startMenu();
            }
        });     
        Button settingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game_settings);
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startPrefs();
            }
        });
        // fill arrays with resources
        id_mc[0] = R.id.mc0;
        id_mc[1] = R.id.mc1;
        id_mc[2] = R.id.mc2;
        id_mc[3] = R.id.mc3;
        id_mc[4] = R.id.mc4;
        id_mc[5] = R.id.mc5;
        id_mc[6] = R.id.mc6;
        id_mc[7] = R.id.mc7;
        id_mc[8] = R.id.mc8;
        id_mc[9] = R.id.mc9;
        id_mc[10] = R.id.mc10;
        id_mc[11] = R.id.mc11;
        id_mc[12] = R.id.mc12;
        id_mc[13] = R.id.mc13;
        id_mc[14] = R.id.mc14;
        id_mc[15] = R.id.mc15;
        img_mc[0][0] = R.drawable.back1;
        img_mc[0][1] = R.drawable.ic_img1;
        img_mc[1][0] = R.drawable.back2;
        img_mc[1][1] = R.drawable.ic_img2;
        img_mc[2][0] = R.drawable.back3;
        img_mc[2][1] = R.drawable.ic_img3;
        img_mc[3][0] = R.drawable.back4;
        img_mc[3][1] = R.drawable.ic_img4;
        img_mc[4][0] = R.drawable.back5;
        img_mc[4][1] = R.drawable.ic_img5;
        img_mc[5][0] = R.drawable.back6;
        img_mc[5][1] = R.drawable.ic_img6;
        img_mc[6][0] = R.drawable.back7;
        img_mc[6][1] = R.drawable.ic_img7;
        img_mc[7][0] = R.drawable.back8;
        img_mc[7][1] = R.drawable.ic_img8;
        img_mc[8][0] = R.drawable.back1;
        img_mc[8][1] = R.drawable.ic_img1;
        img_mc[9][0] = R.drawable.back2;
        img_mc[9][1] = R.drawable.ic_img2;
        img_mc[10][0] = R.drawable.back3;
        img_mc[10][1] = R.drawable.ic_img3;
        img_mc[11][0] = R.drawable.back4;
        img_mc[11][1] = R.drawable.ic_img4;
        img_mc[12][0] = R.drawable.back5;
        img_mc[12][1] = R.drawable.ic_img5;
        img_mc[13][0] = R.drawable.back6;
        img_mc[13][1] = R.drawable.ic_img6;
        img_mc[14][0] = R.drawable.back7;
        img_mc[14][1] = R.drawable.ic_img7;
        img_mc[15][0] = R.drawable.back8;
        img_mc[15][1] = R.drawable.ic_img8;
        //Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(img_mc));
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            myMcs[i] = (Button) findViewById(id_mc[i]);
            myMcs[i].setBackgroundResource(img_mc[i][0]);
            myMcs[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int i = 0;
                    for (int n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
                        if (id_mc[n] == view.getId())
                            i = n;
                    }
                    doClickAction(view, i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void doClickAction(View v, int i)
    {
        v.setBackgroundResource(img_mc[i][1]);
        mc_isfirst = !mc_isfirst;

        // disable all buttons
        for (Button b : myMcs) {
            b.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (mc_isfirst) {
            // turning the first card
            firstid = i;
            // re enable all except this one
            for (Button b : myMcs) {
                if (b.getId() != firstid) {
                    b.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // turning the second card
            secondid = i;   
            doPlayMove();
        }
    }
    private void doPlayMove() {
        mc_counter++;
        if (img_mc[firstid][1] - img_mc[secondid][1] == 0) {
            //correct
            if (b_snd_cor) playSound(R.raw.correct);
            waiting(200);
            myMcs[firstid].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            myMcs[secondid].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            correctcounter++;
        } else {
            //incorrect
            if (b_snd_inc) playSound(R.raw.incorrect);
            waiting(400);
        }
        // reenable and turn cards back
        for (Button b : myMcs) {
            if (b.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE) {
                b.setEnabled(true);
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_back);
                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    myMcs[i].setBackgroundResource(img_mc[i][0]);
                }
            }
        }
        tFeedback.setText("" + correctcounter + " / " + mc_counter);
        if (correctcounter > 7) {
            Intent iSc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scoreboard.class);
            iSc.putExtra("com.gertrietveld.memorygame.SCORE", mc_counter);
            startActivity(iSc);
        }
    }
    public void playSound(int sound) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound);
        mp.setVolume((float).5,(float).5);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }
    public static void waiting(int n) {
        long t0, t1;
        t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        do {
            t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } while ((t1 - t0) < (n));
    }
    private void startMenu() {
        Intent launchMenu = new Intent(this, MenuScreen.class);
        launchMenu.putExtra(COME_FROM,"PlayGame");
        startActivity(launchMenu);
    }
    private void startPrefs() {
        Intent launchPrefs = new Intent(this, Setting.class);
        startActivity(launchPrefs);
    }
    ////////////////////////////////    
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
            Toast.makeText(this, "onRestart-sender is " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**Setting Class**

When the users setting they have option to disable the sound, after they disable it has two buttons: save back to game and save back to menu. But it doesn't do anything after click these two button. It works when i close the app and kill it then open again what i have set up in setting working fine.

```
  public class Setting extends Activity {
        private CheckBox ch_sound_correct, ch_sound_incorrect;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
            ch_sound_correct = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_sound_correct);
            ch_sound_incorrect = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_sound_incorrect);


            Button saveButtonMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_prefs);
            saveButtonMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent launchMenu = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MenuScreen.class);
                    setPreferences(launchMenu);
                }
            });

            Button saveButtonGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_game);
            saveButtonGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent launchGame = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    launchGame.putExtra("SENDER","Settings");   
                    setPreferences(launchGame);
                }
            });

            getPreferences();
        }
        private void getPreferences()
        {

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("memoryPrefs", 0);
            ch_sound_correct.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("play_sound_when_correct", true));
            ch_sound_incorrect.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("play_sound_when_incorrect", true));

        }

        private void setPreferences(Intent theIntent)
        {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("memoryPrefs", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefeditor = settings.edit();
            prefeditor.putBoolean("play_sound_when_correct", ch_sound_correct.isChecked());
            prefeditor.putBoolean("play_sound_when_incorrect", ch_sound_incorrect.isChecked());
            prefeditor.commit();

            //Toast.makeText(this, "setPreferences",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            startActivity(theIntent);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code:

```
recreate();
```

More help of **Activity** **Recreate** method:

void android.app.Activity.recreate()

Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when 
 the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to 
 onDestroy and a new instance then created after it.

**Done**